# Android changing video view to landscape

Tags: android

My application is in Portrait mode and it has one video view in it, on some events i want to rotate only the video view to landscape mode is it possible to do so?

From the code can we modify a single view to be of landscape mode as other will remain in portrait mode?

Also i have `onOrientationChanged` listener in my activity which provides `orientation` values as device orientation changes. how can i determine if device is in landscape or portrait mode from these values?

Answer (score 1):

Yeap, it's possible.
You can get the orientation in runtime with this code:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
//orientation will contain Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT or Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
int orientation = display.getOrientation();
```

So, if you want to make something when changing the orientation you can override the `onConfigurationChanged` method.

And if you want to change the orientation in runtime you can use this (in example, change to portrait):

`setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

If want more details, read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)

Comment: My activity is using `setRequestedOrientation` in `onCreate` method so i am not getting `onConfigurationChanged` event and `getOrientation` also returns `0` every time.

Comment: it looks that 0 is the default. Anyway, getOrientation() is deprecated, if you want, you can use getRotation and discover the rotation, that can be  Surface.ROTATION_0 (no rotation), Surface.ROTATION_90, Surface.ROTATION_180, or Surface.ROTATION_270

Comment: Does this fix only change the `VideoView` to a different size? I have mine at certain width and height in my layout... It looks like this code changes the actual activity orientation (which is not what I'm hoping to find), unless I'm wrong. Just looking to change the dimensions of `VideoView`, if a landscaped video shows in it.